# Cloud Firestore build error on @PropertyName annotation with version 12.0.0

Tags: firebase, google-play-services, google-cloud-firestore

I updated play services and firebase library version from 11.8.0 to 12.0.0 then got the build error at `@PropertyName` annotation for a firestore object.

The error is

`error: cannot find symbol method value()`

Comment: Possibly related: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/fJ9Te3aNa9Q

Comment: Thanks!
Yes, it's the answer.

Comment: Version 12.0.1 containing fix for this was [released today](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)